# "NoReverseMatch at /" when trying to create a link in template

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

I'm following the Django tutorial, and in the [third part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/), they create a link in the template. Now, I followed and wrote a template like this:

```
<ul>
    {% for blog in blogs %}

    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'detail' blog.id %}">
            <h1>{{ blog.name }}</h1>
        </a>
        <p>{{ blog.description }}</p>
    </li>

    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And I have set the urls.py like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

However, when I point my browser to the index, it gives me the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
1 pattern(s) tried: ['$(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

The error details highlight this part of the template:

```
<a href="{% url "detail" blog.id %}">
```

What's going on in here? How do I fix this? I'm using Django 1.8.4.

Comment: 'point my browser to the index' as 'http://domain.tld/index???' or just 'http://domain.tld/' or how?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist at http://localhost:8000/. Before I added the details portion, the front page worked.

Comment: never sure if that is needed, but did you try adding `url(r'^/$', views.index, name='index'),` to your urls?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Just tried, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mispelled in your main `urls.py`, something like.

```
url(r'^polls/$', include('polls.urls')),
```

You have to write like this

```
r'^polls/'. # Note please remove `$` in end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was it!